# React.js does't show anything on the page

Tags: reactjs

I learn React.js. I have a Problem, which I can not solve.
In developer tools I can see only `<div id="root"></div>`  without components, but if I refresh the page and go to network I can see that favicon.ico is not found. Favicon is located in public folder, next to the index.html file. I am not sure if does this couse a problem or not.

[developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbZS4.png)

App.js file:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import BookCreate from './BookCreate';
import BookList from './BookList';
import BooksContext from './context/books';


function App() {
   const { fetchBooks } = useContext(BooksContext)

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchBooks();
   }, [fetchBooks]);

   return (
     <div className='app'>
       <h1>Here is my favorite book list!<br /> If you have one too, please add it</h1>
       <div className='tips'>
         space = new line<br />
         image = open image on google in new tab and copy link
       </div>
       <BookCreate />
       <BookList />
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './style/style.css'
import { Provider } from './context/books';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider>
        <App />
    </Provider>);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>Books</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in Advance!

I tried to delete link with favicon in html, but it didn't help.

Comment: What `Provider` is?

Comment: A missing favicon won't make an app stop working. I would back up, get the bare minimum running, then work forwards. There's not enough information here to help, but at the very least do a hard refresh and avoid the 304.

Comment: What does your `Console` say?  Are there any errors?  You only showed the `Network` tab in dev tools.

Comment: Your issue is probably in `Provider`. In the return function, you need to make sure you are returning `{children}` as well. If you share the code for `Provider` component, can verify.

Comment: Console says anything, is empy. I'm going to check `Provider` now.